# How to Insert auto-generated identity value as part of a hierarchyid field on the same record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hierarchical-data, hierarchyid

I am trying to find a way to insert a record into a table that uses the newly generated Identity value as part of it's hierarchy id.  The following sql demonstrates what I am trying to do, and the closest I have managed to come.  Which is to use an insert followed by an update inside of a transaction.  I'm having trouble coming up with the initial hierarchy id though because there is a unique constraint on that field, and I am worried that could throw an error if 2 elements are being added to the same parent at the same time.

```
DECLARE @hierarchy_elements TABLE (
     id int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
     element_path hierarchyid NOT NULL
)

-- Cheating here, but I need some data to append to.
INSERT INTO @hierarchy_elements(element_path)
SELECT ('/1/')
UNION ALL SELECT ('/1/2/')

-- See that we have a couple elements in the table.
SELECT id, element_path.ToString() as [path] from @hierarchy_elements

-- arbitrarily pick a parent to append to
DECLARE @parentElementId int = 2

-- grab that parent's path.
DECLARE @parentElementPath hierarchyid 
SELECT @parentElementPath = element_path FROM @hierarchy_elements WHERE id = @parentElementId

-- This is what I want to do.  Use the current id as the last part of the hierarchyid
INSERT INTO @hierarchy_elements (element_path)
VALUES(@parentElementPath.ToString() + CAST(scope_identity() AS VARCHAR(20)) + '/')

-- This works, but kind of sucks.
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

-- Insert under the parent with a known invalid id.
INSERT INTO @hierarchy_elements (element_path)
VALUES(@parentElementPath.ToString() + '-1/')

-- now update setting the last element in the hierarchyid to the id just generated.
UPDATE @hierarchy_elements 
SET element_path = @parentElementPath.ToString() + CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS VARCHAR(20)) + '/'
WHERE id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

COMMIT TRANSACTION

-- See that id 3 would fail the unique constraint check, but id 4 is correct.
SELECT id, element_path.ToString() as [path] from @hierarchy_elements
```

If it is possible, I want to do use a single statement insert that will include the new Identity value in the hierarchyid field.

Comment: Tip: You can also use an `OUTPUT` clause to get any data from the rows (Note plural.), e.g. `Id` values.  `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both before and after values in the case of `UPDATE`.  A tool well worth having in your pocket.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think `OUTPUT` supports this case. I need to `INSERT` first, then pipe the output to an `UPDATE` statement.  `UPDATE` after `OUTPUT` doesn't appear to be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea to solve the problem:

Generate ID of the row separately, remember it somewhere, then insert the generated ID as is in the ID column and use the same remembered value to compose the `element_path`.

If you use SQL Server 2012 and above it has a [`SEQUENCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ff878091.aspx) feature. If you are using 2008 and below you can have a separate dedicated table with a single `IDENTITY` column for generating IDs.

So the structure of your main table would be different (id is no longer an `IDENTITY`):

```
DECLARE @hierarchy_elements TABLE (
     id int NOT NULL ,
     element_path hierarchyid NOT NULL
)
```

And you would have a separate object (`SEQUENCE` or a helper table) to generate unique IDs as needed.

You would have an extra explicit step of generating an ID, but you would be able to have only one `INSERT` into the main table without the need of `UPDATE`.

### Second variant

You can use an `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` to "hide" the explicit `UPDATE` statement. This variant is very close to your original approach. You still have to insert something in the `element_path`. That "something" would be adjusted in the trigger using the freshly generated ID by `IDENTITY`.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I ended up doing so I marked it as the answer. I basically created a sequencing table that is just an identity column.  So I insert into that, and use the SCOPE_IDENTITY value from that as my actual record's primary key and in the hierarchy id.